# Angular: How to alternate CSS classes for a list, with more than 2 classes?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have the following `Angular template`. This nicely alternates the style class of each row such that `even-numbered rows` have one class and `odd-numbered rows` have a different class:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="currElement in myCtrl.elementList track by $index" >
    <td ng-class-odd="'element-tilt-left'" ng-class-even="'element-tilt-right'">
      <a ui-sref="myState({elementId: currElement.elementId)" ng-bind="currElement.name">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

But now I want to cycle among 4 different style classes instead of just two. How can I do it?

Comment: Why not just use CSS [`nth-child`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) selectors?

Comment: @Phil I don't think it is supported on ancient browsers.

Comment: @HermLuna neither is AngularJS

Comment: @Phil Ohw I see. I used angularJS before but not get too deep with it. I used ng-repeat and other dependencies. It worked with IE. I just don't know other functions if they will work. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like Divyanshu's answer, but instead of listing all the classes would suggest just computing the class name inline like:

```
ng-class="'class' + $index%4"
```

Here is an update to his fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uL5zd8sy/1/

Comment: Yeah, definitely. Didn't think it that way.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use CSS only with the `nth-child` selector...

```js
angular.module('so', []).run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.elementList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map(function(i) {
    return { name: 'Item ' + i };
  });
});
```

```css
tr:nth-child(4n-3) td {
  background-color: red;    /* Style #1 */
}
tr:nth-child(4n-2) td {
  background-color: green;  /* Style #2 */
}
tr:nth-child(4n-1) td {
  background-color: blue;   /* Style #3 */
  color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(4n) td {
  background-color: black;  /* Style #4 */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table ng-app="so">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="currElement in elementList track by $index">
      <td>
        <a ng-bind="currElement.name"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
ng-class="{class1 : $index%4 == 0, class2 : $index%4 == 1, class3 : $index%4 == 2, class4 : $index%4 == 3}"
```

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/67L9qpv8/1/) fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this would be helpful](http://plnkr.co/edit/DcqdkTQ6MdFHJSU2gltZ?p=preview).

```
.row:nth-child(4n+1){
  color: red;
}

.row:nth-child(4n+2){
  color: green;
}

.row:nth-child(4n+3){
  color: grey;
}

.row:nth-child(4n+4){
  color: blue;
}
```

This would save the angular digest cycle